# Lombok, Spring mongodb and jackson Constructor problem

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, spring-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot and lombok in my project and encounter some issues with it.
My class looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Document(collection = "elements")
public class ElementEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    // ...
}
```

Now, if I use jackson ObjectMapper to create my ElementEntity, I get the following runtime error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `ElementEntity` (no Creators, like default
>   construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate-
>   or property-based Creator)

But if I add the `@NoArgsConstructor` from lombok I get the following compilation error:

> [ERROR] ElementEntity.java:[11,1] constructor ElementEntity() is
>   already defined in class ElementEntity

It seems `@Document` adds one but probably only with package visibility. Is there an easy way to solve this, or I have to manually add a public no args constructor to every `@Document`?

Comment: whats the version of lombok ?

Comment: @benjaminc I'm currently using 1.16.22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a bug in lombok 1.16.22, try upgrading to 1.18.0,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[Read](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1703)

Comment: Thanks, I found this post just now as well, but didn't get that it is fixed in the later version of lombok. Using 1.18.2 now

Answer (score 0):

Try to change id field definition to this:

```
@Id
@Getter
@Setter
private String id;
```

Comment: Hm, \@Data should take care of all the setter and getters. But it only adds the \@RequiredArgsConstructor but not the \@NoArgsConstructor which jackson seems to need.